# MySQL ERROR 1045 in bash script - access denied

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to run a MySQL command from a bash script:

```
mysql --user=[USER] --password=[PASSWORD] --database=[DATABASE] --execute="DELETE FROM table WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY"
```

Both in the bash script and terminal, I get the same error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '[USER]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tested running `mysql -u [USER] -p` and that will connect so I know my credentials are correct.

What am I missing? I've seen a few things online suggesting the port may be wrong, but it's all set running on `localhost`, which is correct

Comment: Do you have modify permissions for that database or table?

Comment: acutally, i've just figured it out: there's a `$` in my password which bash is trying to interpret as a variable. Is there a way to escape the `$` rather than changing my password?

Comment: Using Single quotes around your password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured it out. The problem wasn't the permissions, but the password itself. I needed to escape a `$` in my password, so the code changed to the following (using the password `pass$word`):

```
mysql --user=[USER] --password=pass\$word --database=[DATABASE] --execute="DELETE FROM table WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY"
```

works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

1.maybe you should check into your mysql table `mysql.user` if `USER` and `localhost` in this table, if no add your `USER`

2.check your `USER` privileges if `USER` has right to get into this databases.